# Вёрстка и React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Я по классике делаю вёрстку с использованием `Pug + SASS`. Это быстро и удобно. После этого, вёрстка идёт на бек. Т.к. у меня большой опыт работы на беке, а так же верстать для других бекенд разработчиков, я делаю вёрстку такую, что её не надо исправлять или дорабатывать для бека.

И вот вопрос, как быстрее и проще делать на `React`? Подключать Pug внутрь React не вижу смысла, потому что у Pug свои методы, условия и мешать это не хочется. К тому же, любой другой разработчик должен знать Pug, что бывает редкостью. Но при этом, верстать классическую вёрстку дольше и она не такая лаконичная, как в Pug. Но если делать через Pug, потом надо вручную разбивать на блоки и вставлять в фреймворк.

Поделитесь опытом, как вам удобнее и как быстрее и менее "травмоопасно" на перспективу?

Comment: Допустим библиотека [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)

Answer (score 0):

В реакте нет pug, и верстка там не в том виде, к которому вы привыкли. если вы делаете весь сайт на React.js, то вам весь дом генерирует javascript. И у меня впечатление, что вы не совсем хорошо ознакомились с библиотекой React.js, либо не совсем корректно поставили вопрос.

Comment: если хотите проще и быстрее - Material UI

Comment: Да, с Material UI знаком. Но тут вопрос кастомной вёрстки. Скорее всего я непонятно задал вопрос. В jsx вёрстка в том же виде, просто данные меняются. Тут вопрос немного в другом. Я просто обычно делаю вёрстку, потом кусками переношу в Реакт. Клиенты обычно хотят видеть промежуточные версии. Ну вот и задался вопросом, а что быстрее и лучше. Сам не пробовал, как-то не требовалось. https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug - не тестил, вот сегодня загуглил, но мне не нравится эта идея